# On Windows 10/11, How to delete Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\WaaS\Upfc?

Tags: windows, registry, windows-update

Resource Update Manager 95% failing on 2 Registry Keys

Hi,

When using RUM 95% of my machines have processing warnings. When checking the logs I always see these two entries:

\xxx Registry Error 5 Access is denied. SYSTEM\WaaS\Upfc (RegCreateKeyEx)
\xxx Registry Error 5 Access is denied. SYSTEM\WaaS\WaaSMedic (RegCreateKeyEx)

I understand this is part of Windows As A Service, and refers to part of the Windows Update processes.

Is there anyway to stop this error happening? It is a bit annoying have to check all of the Warnings, which would show as 'OK' if it was not for these two registry keys.

We're only processing Windows 10, and most machines are 1809, but it does not make a difference what version (1803, 1709 etc)